# Is there a less convoluted way to set the $path array locally within function?

Tags: shell-script, scripting, zsh

Is there a less laborious way for setting a local version of the `$path` array than what's shown in the following snippet?

```
foo () {
    local holdpath
    holdpath=($path)
    local path
    path=($holdpath)
    if ( some_condition ) path=( $PREFIX $path )

    # do stuff
}
```

I'm referring specifically to the song-and-dance with `holdpath`...

If instead I define

```
foo () {
    local path=($path)
    if ( some_condition ) path=( $PREFIX $path )

    # do stuff
}
```

...the first assignment to `path` triggers a `bad pattern` error.  Of course, if instead I define

```
foo () {
    local path
    path=($path)
    if ( some_condition ) path=( $PREFIX $path )

    # do stuff
}
```

...the first assignment to `path` makes no difference (i.e. it can be omitted without altering the results); with or without it, `$path` will be empty.

EDIT:

The following script tests the various suggestions I've gotten so far:

```
foo_0 () {
  echo ${#path}
  local PATH=$PATH
  echo ${#path}
}

foo_1 () {
  echo ${#path}
  eval "local path; path=(${(q)path})"
  echo ${#path}
}

foo_2 () {
  echo ${#path}
  eval "$(local -p path)"
  echo ${#path}
}

for i ( 0 1 2 ) {
  fn=foo_$i
  echo "# $fn"
  $fn
  echo
}
```

The output is:

```
# foo_0
22
22

# foo_1
22
1

# foo_2
22
22
```

So the outputs for `foo_0` and `foo_2` are at least consistent with what I'm trying to achieve.  Something is not working with `foo_1` as given above, but I get rid of the `(q)` in the assignment to `path`, i.e.

```
foo_1 () {
  echo ${#path}
  eval "local path; path=($path)"
  echo ${#path}
}
```

...then the output agrees with that of `foo_0` and `foo_2`.  Unfortunately, even after reading the documentation for the `q` qualifier a couple of times, I don't quite understand what it's supposed to be doing in the original recipe.

Also, I cannot understand why the following command-line variant of `foo_0` differs from the one above:

```
% (foo_0a () { echo ${#path}; local PATH=$PATH; echo ${#path} }; foo_0a)
22
1
```

FWIW, the corresponding command-line variants of `foo_1` and `foo_2` produce the same results as their originals in the script:

```
% (foo_1a () { echo ${#path}; eval "local path; path=(${(q)path})"; echo ${#path} }; foo_1a)
22
1
% (foo_2a () { echo ${#path}; eval "$(local -p path)"; echo ${#path}; }; foo_2a)
22
22
```

Also, in all the cases above in which `echo ${#path}` produces `1` instead of `22` the reason is that the local `$path` variable contains all the individual paths in a single string, separated by spaces.

Comment: A note of warning: use `holdpath=("$path[@]")`. `holdpath=($path)` removes the empty elements.

Comment: ++Thanks for the pointer, and for editing the many typos in my original post!

Comment: I can't reproduce your experience with `foo_0a`; however, in the process of trying, I noticed that if you have a path component which includes a `:`, then setting `PATH=$PATH` increases the size of `$path`, as I suppose you might expect. So my solution is not correct in that case. But I can't explain your result either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While for *tied* arrays, you can use [rici's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/80771/22565), in the general case, you could do:

```
foo() {
  eval "local array; array=(${(q)array[@]})"
  ...
}
```

The `(q)` is to quote the elements of the arrays. For instance, for a value of `$PATH` like `/foo bar:/x$y`, `"${(q)path[@]}"` would expand to `/foo\ bar /x\$y`. We need to escape those space and dollar characters because that string is passed to `eval`.

You could also do:

```
foo() {
  eval "$(local -p array)"
  ...
}
```

which would work with any type of variable, but that forks an extra process.

Comment: Thanks!  I ran into some problems with your first suggestion; please the latest EDIT to my post.

Comment: @kjo, yes of course, sorry, because `${(q)path}` was inside double quotes, that quotes a single argument. My last edit should fix it.

Comment: Not sure if that really counts as less convoluted!

Answer (score 5):

Use the scalar `PATH` form instead of the array `path`. Making either of these local effectively makes both of them local, so:

```
foo() {
  local PATH=$PATH
  if ( some_condition ) path=( $PREFIX $path )

  # do stuff
}
```

(Note that this will not work if some path component has an embedded `:`.)

Unfortunately, it is not possible to initialize a local array parameter in one statement, making it impossible to initialize a local array parameter using its original value.

Comment: Well, if elements of `$path` have colons, it's not the only thing that won't work since `$PATH` cannot contain a directory name with colon: zsh will be able to search in there, but not the other tools, and for instance, if you do `path+=(~/:::)`  to add your weirdly named `bin` directory, `zsh` will find executables in there but other tools (think `env`, `xargs`...) will look for them in the current directory (3 times) which is dangerous.